how to set mediapipe error for dataset path
when i run this code it gives an error of image directory dataset is empty while the directory is valid and its also show content when using another method i think the problem is with gesture recognizer
import os
# Load train and validation datasets
train_data = gesture_recognizer.Dataset.from_folder(train_dataset_path)
validation_data = gesture_recognizer.Dataset.from_folder(validation_dataset_path)

# Print dataset sizes
print("train_data size: ", len(train_data))
print("validation_data size: ", len(validation_data))

Error:--------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[5], line 5
      1 import os
      4 # Load train and validation datasets
----> 5 train_data = gesture_recognizer.Dataset.from_folder(train_dataset_path)
      6 validation_data = gesture_recognizer.Dataset.from_folder(validation_dataset_path)
      8 # Print dataset sizes

File /opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/mediapipe_model_maker/python/vision/gesture_recognizer/dataset.py:176, in Dataset.from_folder(cls, dirname, hparams)
    174 all_image_paths = list(tf.io.gfile.glob(data_root + r'/*/*'))
    175 if not all_image_paths:
--> 176   raise ValueError('Image dataset directory is empty.')
    178 if not hparams:
    179   hparams = HandDataPreprocessingParams()

ValueError: Image dataset directory is empty.

when i run this code it gives an error of image directory dataset is empty while the directory is valid and its also show content when using another method i think the problem is with gesture recognizer 
import os


    # Load train and validation datasets
    train_data = gesture_recognizer.Dataset.from_folder(train_dataset_path)
    validation_data = gesture_recognizer.Dataset.from_folder(validation_dataset_path)

    # Print dataset sizes
    print("train_data size: ", len(train_data))
    print("validation_data size: ", len(validation_data))

Error:--------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[5], line 5
      1 import os
      4 # Load train and validation datasets
----> 5 train_data = gesture_recognizer.Dataset.from_folder(train_dataset_path)
      6 validation_data = gesture_recognizer.Dataset.from_folder(validation_dataset_path)
      8 # Print dataset sizes

File /opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/mediapipe_model_maker/python/vision/gesture_recognizer/dataset.py:176, in Dataset.from_folder(cls, dirname, hparams)
    174 all_image_paths = list(tf.io.gfile.glob(data_root + r'/*/*'))
    175 if not all_image_paths:
--> 176   raise ValueError('Image dataset directory is empty.')
    178 if not hparams:
    179   hparams = HandDataPreprocessingParams()

ValueError: Image dataset directory is empty

